# Github Deployment Process

Tags: git, github, command-line

I am trying to understand how to deploy something using git commands on command line rather than on the github interface. Please let me know if this would successfully merge changes from a separate branch to my master:

`git branch` *to see which branch you’re on*

`git status` *to see which files have not been added to master that have been changed on the branch you’re on*

`git commit –m “string”` *takes note of what you did or what changes were made*

`git add –A` *adds all files with all changes to the branch you are on*

`git diff` *see what differences are between the master and the branch you’re on*

`git checkout master` *changes position to be in master*

`git push origin master` *before, the changes I made were on the Head of my local working copy on the branch I was in. gotta use push origin to send those changes to your remote repository*

`git fetch origin` *grabs the remote with all of the branches (including the one where you made your changes)*

`git merge origin/master` *combine the changes on the remote to the local branch*

`git log` *see the record of the commits*

Thank you so much!

Comment: You need to do git add before your commit I believe.

Comment: add before commit, diff won't show anything if you've already added unless you use `--staged`, push before switch branch, and merging the branch you just pushed won't do anything

Comment: `git add` , then `git commit` then `git push`   if this is the first time pushing to this specific remote branch then `git push -u origin master`

Comment: Okay, so then the order is  ``git branch`` , ``git status`` , ``git add –A`` , ``git commit –m “string”``, ``git diff``, ``git checkout master``, ``git push origin master``, ``git fetch origin`` , ``git merge origin/master`` , ``git log``

Comment: Is that right, @Scott Selby

Answer (score 0):

After testing my theory, with the help of @Scott Selby, @doelleri, and @PolarisUser, here is the correct order of the git commands:

`Git branch` which states your current position/what branch your in

`git branch branchname` makes a new branch called branchname

`git checkout branchname` switch to the new branch branchname

`git diff branchname master` to see the differences between branchname and the master branch (this step can happen anywhere in the order, i.e., it doesn't need to happen after you create a branch)

`git status` lists the files you need to add before you commit

`git add –A` adds all files (including the file or files you changed) to branchname

`git commit –m “I made this change”` makes a quick record of the changes you made in the branch that you are in, aggregating all changes that you stashed, then blobbing them all into one commit and represents all changes

`git checkout master` moves you out of branchname and into the master so you can pull (fetch/merge) all of your changes you made to branchname

`git fetch origin` brings the remote server on a local level. The remote server includes all of the branches being used to create a project

`git merge origin/master` merges all changes you made on your remote, which has the changes you made on branchname, with master. Now this is all still on a local level. To actually deploy these changes that you made you must do the next command

`git push origin master` sends your changes to Github’s actual remote server